SSE closing when .net controller also handles a POST
I'm building a simple chat with an LLM application. I want an initial POST request (the human users first message to be the trigger which results in a response from the llm.
S0, I have a ASP.net core web api controller which has an endpoint for handling an SSE connection and has an additional endpoint for handling a POST request (this allows the user to send messages up).
The Angular app Im built (being served by node and making use of the proxy.conf) makes an EventSource connection to my controller. If I hardcode an users initial question on the server so I dont have to make my POST request, the SSE sends down the llms response as expected.
// Endpoint for streaming chat messages
[HttpGet("stream")]
public async Task GetChatMessagesAsStreamAsync()
{

    string prompt = """
        Heres my lovely prompt
        """;


    await _agentGroupChatService.AddChatMessage(new ChatRequest { Message= prompt });

    // Set the response content type for SSE
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";

    // Stream messages from the service
    await foreach (var message in _agentGroupChatService.GetChatMessagesAsStreamAsync())
    {
        var messageJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message);
        // Write each message in SSE format
        await HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"data: {messageJson}\n\n");
        await HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync(); // Flush to send the message immediately


    }
}

BUT... If I make the SSE connection, and then rely on the POST request to send up the initial message, the SSE connection immediately drops (marked as cancelled in the client).
This cancellation happens before the POST controller endpoint executes - its only responding with a ok anyway!
[HttpPost("message")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendMessage([FromBody] ChatRequest chatRequest)
{
  
    return Ok(); // Respond with 200 OK
}

// Endpoint for streaming chat messages
[HttpGet("stream")]
public async Task GetChatMessagesAsStreamAsync()
{

    // Set the response content type for SSE
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";

    // Stream messages from the service
    await foreach (var message in _agentGroupChatService.GetChatMessagesAsStreamAsync())
    {
        var messageJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message);
        // Write each message in SSE format
        await HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"data: {messageJson}\n\n");
        await HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync(); // Flush to send the message immediately


    }
}

In fact if the POST controller endpoint just returns an OK, the SSE connection cancels!
Further if data is sent down via the event stream first, I can send post request. If no data has been sent down prior to the post, it fails.
Any thoughts on whats going on?
